# HTML Parse no results

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Am trying to parse this HTML document to get the contents of flight, time, origin, date and output.

```
<div id="FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr class="">
    <td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/US.gif" title="US AIRWAYS. " alt="US AIRWAYS. " /></td>
    <td class="flight">US5316</td>
    <td class="codeshare">NZ46</td>
    <td class="origin">Rarotonga</td>
    <td class="date">02 Sep</td>
    <td class="time">10:30</td>
    <td class="est">21:30</td>
    <td class="status">CHECK IN CLOSING</td>
    </tr>
```

I am using this code, based on HTML Agility Pack for windows phone 7 to find and output the content of `<td class="flight">US5316</td>`

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var html = e.Result;

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);


    var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
        .Element("table")
        .Element("tbody")
        .Elements("tr")
        .Where(tr => tr.GetAttributeValue("td", "").Contains("class"))
        .SelectMany(tr => tr.Descendants("flight"))
        .ToArray();

    this.scrollViewer1.Content = node;  

   //Added below

   listBox1.itemSource = node;
}
```

I get no results in either the ScrollViewer or the Listbox. I would like to know if the linq parse that I am using is correct for the HTML I supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you intend to do with this line?

```
.Where(tr => tr.GetAttributeValue("td", "").Contains("class"))
```

`GetAttributeValue(name, def)` looks for an attribute with the key `name` in the node, and it returns the value of that attribute in case it founds it. Otherwise, it returns the default value `def`.

So what's actually happening here is that `<tr>` doesn't have any attribute with the key `td`, so it's returning the default value (an empty string), which does not contain the substring "class", so your `<tr>` node is being filtered out.

**Edit**:
This will return an array where each entry is an array of 8 strings containing the contents of each td:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
    .Element("table")
    .Element("tbody")
    .Elements("tr")
    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Examples:

```
node[0][1] == "US5316"
node[0][3] == "Rarotonga"
```

Comment: thanks for some constructive feedback. I am very new to c# and learning more everyday. I thought I was getting all the Attributes `"class"` from the element `<td>`. Is there any chance you would be able to give me an example of code that would return the values inside flight, airline, origin etc..?

Comment: Sure, I added an example there. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get this value "Rarotonga" from this ` <td class="origin">Rarotonga</td>` and US5316 from `<td class="flight">US5316</td>` etc.. as single values or variables which I can then output to textbox or listbox. Thanks your help on this, you dont know how much time I have spent with different variations.

Comment: In that case, having an array per `<tr>` might be better. Each entry will be an array of 8 items containing the values of the properties. I edited the answer again to accomplish this. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks again for your help on this, I will try this code out tonight and let you know.

Comment: You are a genius!! This is EXACTLY what I was after and work perfectly. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the content of a ScrollViewer to a `string[]` (an array). So I'll repeat myself, and say that you should take some time to learn basic C# before you continue this endeavour.

What you need to do, is to use a `ListBox` instead of the `ScrollViewer` and then set the `ListBox.ItemSource` to your `node` string-array.

Comment: I have already tried that but I still get no output at all. I realize I could know more about c# but surely i am entitled to ask a question without you consistently telling me i need to learn the basics.

Comment: Just so you understand I am only using the scrollviewer to check the results from the parse before I start otuputing to listbox and binding. The array should display the same in the scrollviewer as in the listbox, but niether have any results, hence the question. If you have an idea why the `string[]` (array) is showing no results then please feel free to input.